# Android test code coverage, Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way to run unit tests for Android from Eclipse in a way that will instrument the code and measure test code coverage?

I'm looking for a simple way to find out which parts of my application aren't tested yet, fix the test cases and see if that helped.

Answer (score 8):

**Disclaimer: I'm an Atlassian**

The Atlassian Clover tool has also support for Android - it measures coverage for both application code and unit tests. Although in alpha stage, it works quite well - it works with Eclipse version 3.6.2 and higher.

If you want to find areas of your application which require improvement, then the following Clover features will be perfect for this task:

- Clover Dashboard
- Coverage Cloud Report
- Coverage TreeMap Report
- Coverage Explorer

Oh, and the Clover HTML Report looks fantastic!

Check this: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover-for-Android

Answer (score 3):

I've been used EMMA (android already support it) for code coverage (and [android-junit-report](http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/) for test reports), here is a summary:

- Create android project (or library)

> android.bat update project -p project -n my_project -t android-16
>
> cd project
>
> ant **emma** clean debug

- create a test project (linked to previous library)

> android.bat update project **--library ..\project** -p project_Test -n project_Test -t

- in case the main project is not a library

> android.bat update project **-m ..\project** -p project_Test -n project_Test -t
>
> ant **emma** clean debug **install** 
>   I ddidn't use 'test' since I want to run my own instrument
>
> adb shell am instrument **-e coverage true -e coverageFile sdcard/coverage.ec** -w com..myproject.test/*com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner*

- Pull files from device (emulator)

> adb pull sdcard/junit-report.xml
>
> adb pull sdcard/coverage.ec

- Generate **XML** report (can also generate html report)

> java -cp emma.jar emma report -r xml -in bin/coverage.em,coverage.ec

- Generate **HTML** report (can also generate html report)

> java -cp emma.jar emma report -r html -in bin/coverage.em,coverage.ec

- Using Post-builds (Jenkins):

  - JUnit report XML
  - Emma Coverage report (give the coverage.xml as input)

**Don't** need the emma.jar into libs

Check it out from my [blog](http://mobiledevtest.blogspot.co.il/2014/02/android-unit-tests-with-code-coverage.html)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this article: http://blog.pboos.ch/2011/06/coverage-fo-android-tests/

EDIT: Updated link: https://github.com/pboos/blog.pboos.ch/blob/master/_posts/2011-06-29-coverage-fo-android-tests.markdown

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This link is now broken.

Answer (score 2):

Install [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) from Eclipse Marketplace.

If you have `<path to test project>/build.xml` file rename it.

I was able to generate test coverage report by executing following from the console:

`<path to android tools>android update test-project -m <path to app project> -p <path to test project>` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

`cd <path to test project>` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

`ant emma debug install test` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

where `<path to android tools>` is `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/` on my machine - the folder where android SDK is installed.

This generated `<path to test project>/bin/coverage.html` file.

If you get "wrong JAVA_HOME" error execute `gksu gedit /etc/environment` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, correct `JAVA_HOME`, save the file, log out or reboot and try again.

Source: http://blog.rabidgremlin.com/2010/11/19/android-tips-generating-a-coverage-report-for-your-unit-tests/