# How to run my android project in coverage mode in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android test code coverage, Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282702/android-test-code-coverage-eclipse)

I have already installed eclemma plug-in for eclipse and i can see luncher icon in eclipse too but when i lunch my project in coverage mode it warns me with

> No coverage data file has been written during coverage session.

beside this says plz make sure ur project doesny include emma run time library. or emma configuration setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid EclEmma doesn't support Android JUnit tests.

Comment: then what is the  use of  eclemma plugin-in in eclipse????