# In eclipse, anything that can replace djUnit?

Tags: eclipse

I just heard this useful tools djUnit ([djUnit](http://works.dgic.co.jp/djunit/)) plugin for eclipse to do testing, which can also generate a code coverage report. Anything that can do this job replacing this plugin?

Comment: What exactly would you require from an alternative, that djUnit doesn't do? It isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody is answering my questions, I tried to google it and found some methods and want to share with you.

1 EclEmma

2  Emma

3 java development tools

4 Clover

There are also other questions and discussioins at this community, like [this one:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282702/android-test-code-coverage-eclipse)